Power Automate Power BI Scheduled report can not read data from second Data Model (Semantic Model)
My Power BI report has two data sources from two different workspaces.
Part 1 of report renders fine, But when I use second semantic model for report from a different workspace. Power Automate fails to render the report.

Report Part 1: renders fine (workspace 1)
Report Part 2: Error (workspace 2)



Can you please share the error you are receiving ?

Sorry. Error does not show I don't have access to power bi server logs.

The issue was fixed by using Right power automate request. passing correct identity values in request.

Correct power automate Request for multiple dataset with RLS:


Correct power automate Request for multiple dataset with RLS: 
{
    "host": {
        "connectionReferenceName": "shared_powerbi",
        "operationId": "InitiateExportToFileForPbiReports"
    },
    "parameters": {
        "groupid": "workspace GUID",
        "reportid": "workspace GUID",
        "ExportPayloadPowerBIReport/format": "PDF",
        "ExportPayloadPowerBIReport/PowerBIReportExportConfiguration/identities": [
            {
                "username": "testuser@abk.com",
                "datasets": [
                    "dataset 1 guid",
                    "dataset 2 guid"
                ],
                "roles": [
                    "RLS ROLE 1",
                    "RLS ROLE 1"
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}



